# SQLite Error ")" closing bracket

Tags: php, sqlite

What in the world is wrong with the following SQL?

I'm using SQLite and I cannot figure out what is wrong with it.

```sql
CREATE TABLE users 
(
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    email TEXT
    name TEXT,
    description TEXT,
    date_joined INTEGER,
);
```

I am getting an extremely ambiguous error:

> Error: near ")": syntax error

Comment: Is the trailing comma after INTEGER required?

Comment: Did not know that. I removed it and it was fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to delete the comma after the last column definition:

```sql
CREATE TABLE users 
(
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    email TEXT
    name TEXT,
    description TEXT,
    date_joined INTEGER
);
```